Tables located at th end of document
I want to transfer a table of Data from Excel to Word but i'm facing a problem.
I want the following architecture for my word document :

A title
The table containing some data
For each row of the table, create a new page and insert pictures linked to the data

I can create all the objects but my table always end at the end of the document, no matter what I try.
I just want to have this table starting on my second page.
Thnk you in advance for your help.
Here is my code :
    ' ouvrir Word
    Dim WdApp As Object
    Set WdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WdApp.Visible = True
    ' Créer un nouveau document
    Set Doc = WdApp.Documents.Add
    WdApp.Selection.typetext "Line of Sight" ' Ajouter un titre
    
    ' Insérer le tableau des coordonnées au début du document
    WdApp.Selection.InsertNewPage
    Set DataRange = Worksheets("Export DWG").Range("A4:M" & nbpoints + 3)
    
    
    Set myRange = WdApp.Selection.Range
    Set CoordsTable = WdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=myRange, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=4, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, Autofitbehavior:=WdAutoFitBehavior)
    WdApp.Selection.MoveEnd
        
    For i = 1 To nbpoints
        Set DataRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("A4:H" & nbpoints + 3) ' Range de données de la feuille "Data"
        LaserNumber = DataRange(i, 5)
        pointName = DataRange(i, 1)
        
        Debug.Print "---> " & i & " : " & pointName
        
        WdApp.Selection.InsertNewPage
        WdApp.Selection.typetext ("Some Text")
        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        WdApp.Selection.typetext "Subtitle"
        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        ' >>> Add a first image

        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        WdApp.Selection.typetext "Other Subtitle"
        WdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        ' >>> Add a second image
    Next i
    
    Debug.Print ">>> Fin remplissage document ..."
    MsgBox "Document has been filled, please select the Word window and choose a sensitivity label."
    

I used step-by-step debug mode and here is what I can conclude :

The first page with title are OK
Then the new page and the table are created without any issue
Then, the next page is created and the table is moved to the end of the document.

I tried to use .InsertAfter to put some texte and try to move selection, the text was well displayed but the table still moved. I tried Selection.MoveEnd, but it didn't change anything.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78773273/content-is-out-of-order-when-using-excel-vba-to-create-a-word-document

Thank you, that was the solution : collapse to end and insert break
